# Vuex: Why array in state is mutated (possibly via a computed property) even though not committed / dispatched

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The following code is a very simple app. The App mounts, receives list of quotes via (firebase's) value event from a ref/endpoint, pushes to `allQuotes` array in `home.vue`.

Then in `QuoteList.vue`,   just displays this list using a `getter` for `quoteList`.

```
computed: {
                myAllQuotes() {
                    return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
                }
            }
```

Though this setup works, but I cannot understand why `quotesList` in `store.js` gets mutated automatically even though it ISN'T explicitly mutated (using `set_allQuotes` (a store setter)) in any of the components using it.

I *suspect* the following code snippet in `home.vue` is somehow updating `quoteList` (in store) but I'm cannot understand the logic behind a **computed property mutating** the store state.

**Home.vue**

```
computed: {
            allQuotes() {
                return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
            }
        },
```

Here is the complete code,

**Main.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import { store } from './store/store.js'

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    })
```

**Store.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            quotesList: [],
        },
        getters: {
            get_quotesList(state) {
                return state.quotesList
            }
        },
        mutations: {
             set_allQuotes(state, value) {
                state.quotesList = value
            }
        }
    })
```

**App.vue**

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import home from './home.vue'
        export default {
            components: {
                home
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <quote-list />
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import quoteList from './components/QuoteList.vue'

        export default {
            computed: {
                allQuotes() {
                    return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
                }
            },
            components: {
                quoteList
            },
            methods: {
                get_allQuotes: function() {
                    var vm = this;
                    quotesRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                        snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
                            vm.allQuotes.push({
                                key: snap.key,
                                category: snap.val().category,
                                quoteTxt: snap.val().quoteTxt
                            })
                        })
                    })
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.get_allQuotes()
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**QuoteList.vue**

```
    <template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 quotes-list-wrapper">
                <template v-for="(quote,idx) in myAllQuotes">
                    <div class="quote-block-item">
                        <p class="quote-txt"> {{quote.quoteTxt}} </p>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            computed: {
                myAllQuotes() {
                    return this.$store.getters.get_quotesList;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Note**: `vue-router` is used but've omitted putting the router code (routes and router-links), for terseness.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update the computed property in your Home.vue file. The code block is this :

```js
snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
                            vm.allQuotes.push({
                                key: snap.key,
                                category: snap.val().category,
                                quoteTxt: snap.val().quoteTxt
                            })
                        })
```

If you try to change the computed property directly, vue will replace it with your state on each tick. So this is not a true approach. If you want to change the state you should do that by actions and mutations.

Hope this helps.